# About rxjs operators

Tags: angular, rxjs

```js
place = new BehaviourSubject<Place[]>([new Place(..), new Place(..)]);
```

suppose we have created new place

```js
fun(){
    this.place.pipe(tap(1)).subscribe(places => {
        this.places.next(places.concat(newplace));
    });
}
```

My question is - when we are using these `tap(1)` what does it mean like it will an object from an array or it will take the whole list? how we can know that it will take a list or an object?

Answer (score 1):

I just assume a few things.

**a:** You want to emit an Object to the BehaviourSubject and retrieve it:

Then "tap(...)" is a peek operation for the pipeline. Wich means, if you emit an object,
You have here the option to create a side effect with the object.
"tap(1)" will create an error, since it expects a function.

If you want to use tap, it could look like this :

```js
this.place.pipe(tap(value => console.log(JSON.stringify(value))).subscribe(value => {
   // do something.
   // but befor you do something, a value will be logged.
   // since you are throwing an Array into the Subject, the whole array will be
   // emitted as one object. 
}
```

**b:** You expect, that multiple items will be emitted, but you only want the first one.

Here you want to use the "take(1)" operation in the pipe. Wich makes sure, you get one and EXACTLY one item, and then the subscription will end, since the resulting observable
of the end of the pipe will complete if ONE item is emitted.

```js
this.place.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(value => {
   // do something
}
```

**c:** You want to emit each item of the value seperately.

Here you can "transform" the Array to an Observable, that emits each value sepearately.

```js
 place: Observable<Place> = Observable.of([new Place(..), new Place(..)]);

fun(): void{
 this.place.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(value => {
   // will give you the first item and then completes
 }
}

fun2():void{
 this.place.pipe(tap(value => console.log(JSON.stringify(value))).subscribe(value => {
   // this callback will be called for each single Value of the pipe.
   // also the tap() will log, each single value. 
 }
}
```

**Note:**
A BehaviourSubject will emit each value, and will store the latest.
You should probably try some things with RxJs to understand better how they work.
RxJs is a bit annoying in the beginning, because the learningcurve is more like a Rollercoaster.
But you should understand it, if you will work with it, because there are many things that work really well with it, but there are workaround that are floating arround, if you don't understand the Concept of "Observable Streams" and "reactive programming", that will cause a lot of technical dept.